# False answer from an equation

Tags: roots

If you have the equation 
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + 1 = 0,
$$
and you solve it like this
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + 1 = 0
$$
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = -1
$$
$$
-x = 1
$$
$$
x = -1,
$$
everything's good. But if you do it like this
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + 1 = 0
$$
$$ 
\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = -1
$$
*multiply both sides by x*
$$
x = -x
$$
*divide by x*
$$
1 = -1,
$$
you get nonsense.
What is going on? What am I missing here.

Comment: When you multiply both sides by $x$ , $ \frac{1}{x} * x =1$, not $x$.

Comment: The incorrect line is "_multiply both sides by x:_ $x=-x$." It should have been $1=-x$. Remember that $(\frac1x)x=\frac xx=1$.

Comment: Is this a joke?

Answer (score 4):

You've made a computational error.

$$\frac{1}{x}=-1$$

multiply both sides by $x$ gives

$$1=-x$$

Math is still safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong.  The first is that you have multiplied $\frac{1}{x}$ by $x$ and got $x$ instead of $1$.

The second is that you have divided by a variable without first determining that the variable is not equal to zero.

Comment: If you have x = -x, the only time when that's true is when x=0, but if x=0, you can't solve the equation by dividing by x. Am I correct?

Comment: Right, you would solve it by adding x to both sides and then dividing by 2.

Answer (score -2):

$\frac1x*x=1 $ not $x$.You have got it wrong.